# Change array key from string to integer value with the array values still intact.

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

i am retrieving result as array from the database using codeigniter like this:

`Array([name]=>TempName [hobby]=>Programming)`

and i would like to change the above array like this:

`Array([0]=>Tempname [1]=>Programming)`

i would like to change the key(`name,hobby`) from column name to integer value(`0,1`)....

i have no idea about this...how i can change the key from string to integer...

any help or suggestion would be a great help, thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you can use the array_values method https://www.php.net/array_values

Answer (score 2):

`array_values` may be what you are looking for